Azure Virtual Desktop KQL (Kusto) query
I 'm looking for a KQL (Kusto) query that gives me the total number of users per application or per application group for an Azure Virtual Desktop hostpool from the Log Analytics Workspace.
This query gives the total number of users per hostpool, but I would to distinct that further:
WVDConnections
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d) 
| where State == "Connected" 
| project _ResourceId, UserName
| project-rename Hostpool = _ResourceId 
| summarize DistinctUsers= dcount(UserName) by Hostpool
| extend HostPool=toupper(strcat(split(Hostpool, "/")[4], ".", split(Hostpool, "/")[8]))
| project HostPool, DistinctUsers

Thanks!
It is not giving enough information.

What information is missing and what is your actual question?

Also have a look at this answer. It sounds very similar to your question.

This is the question: I 'm looking for a KQL (Kusto) query that gives me the total number of users per application or per application group for an Azure Virtual Desktop hostpool from the Log Analytics Workspace.

Your query looks good. Which information is missing?

Yes, this query is working, but I also want to export the users per application group (desktops &  remoteapps).

WVDConnections
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(10d)
| summarize Users = make_set(UserName) by ApplicationGroupName
| project ApplicationGroupName, Users => gives an error ApplicationGroupmame is unknown

I am a little bit further, see below.

Have you already tried this (the datatable is only for testing purposes):
let WVDConnections = datatable(TimeGenerated: datetime, UserName: string, ApplicationGroupName: string)
[
    datetime(2024-07-01 08:00:00), "user1@example.com", "DesktopGroup1",
    datetime(2024-07-02 09:00:00), "user2@example.com", "DesktopGroup1",
    datetime(2024-07-03 10:00:00), "user3@example.com", "RemoteAppGroup1",
    datetime(2024-07-04 11:00:00), "user1@example.com", "RemoteAppGroup1",
    datetime(2024-07-05 12:00:00), "user4@example.com", "DesktopGroup2",
    datetime(2024-07-07 13:00:00), "user2@example.com", "RemoteAppGroup2",
    datetime(2024-07-07 14:00:00), "user5@example.com", "RemoteAppGroup2",
    datetime(2024-07-08 15:00:00), "user3@example.com", "DesktopGroup1",
    datetime(2024-07-09 16:00:00), "user6@example.com", "DesktopGroup2",
    datetime(2024-07-10 17:00:00), "user1@example.com", "RemoteAppGroup2"
];
WVDConnections
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(10d) 
| summarize Users = make_set(UserName) by ApplicationGroupName
| project ApplicationGroupName, Users

Sample code here.

WVDConnections
| where TimeGenerated > ago(7d)
| where State == "Connected"
| project _ResourceId, ResourceAlias, UserName
| project-rename Hostpool = _ResourceId
| project-rename Application = ResourceAlias
| extend HostPool=toupper(strcat(split(Hostpool, "/")[4], ".", split(Hostpool, "/")[8]))
| summarize DistinctUsers= dcount(UserName) by Application, Hostpool

And what is missing?

No, I think it's good now.

@Jaap2024  If I could help you, feel free to accept this answer. Thx.
